# Word Wrap in Email HTML

Tags: html, vb.net

I have a program that sends dataset data as an html Email.  It all works great, except the output randomly uses word wrap in the table so the last letter or 2 letters of the word goes below it.  The current output looks like this:

```
Time    07:08   Jarro
                d
```

Obviously I'd like it to look like this:

```
Time    07:08   Jarrod
```

My HTML Code is:

```
<html>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr><th>Description</th><th> Location </th></tr>
                    <%= From time In Me._Dataset.Time.AsEnumerable _
                        Select <tr><td>Time</td>
                                   <td><%= time.dtTimeIn.ToString("hh:mm tt") %></td>
                                   <td style="white-space: nowrap"><%= time.SName %></td></tr> %>
```

Comment: What are you reading the email with? Thunderbird is more likely to display your html correctly than Outlook, for example.

Comment: Interesting comment.  iPad and iPhone show the information correctly.  Outlook is the only one having the issue...  Would that indicate there is not a "Fix"?

Comment: I mentioned it because your question sounded too vague and this sounded like the most important missing detail that could have been helpful to people trying to answer your question. My understanding is that Outlook 2007 and later can't actually handle HTML natively (they convert it to RTF first) so it could have been important to know that it was Outlook that you were having the problem with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add fixed width for `<td>`. for example `<td width="150">` or `<td style="width:150px;">`